# Simple view controller help

Tags: xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

All I wanted was a simple view controller setup. So when you click on a button it switches to a designated view and appears with a nav controller bar at the top. I would like to do this in a view of a tab bar controller.

I just need to know what connections to make in interface builder for this to work.

I have my specified code in the appdelegates h and m.

**My .H**

```
//navigation controller

UINavigationController *navigationController;

//view controller

UIViewController *LibraryVC;
UIViewController *OrganizeVC;
UIViewController *DiscoverVC;
UIViewController *NavigationBarVC;

//buttons

UIButton *LibraryButton;
UIButton *OrganizeButton;
UIButton *DiscoverButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *LibraryVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *OrganizeVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *DiscoverVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *NavigationBarVC;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *LibraryButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *OrganizeButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *DiscoverButton;

-(IBAction)next;
-(IBAction)next2;
-(IBAction)next3;
```

**MY .M**

```
@synthesize navigationController;

@synthesize LibraryVC;
@synthesize OrganizeVC;
@synthesize DiscoverVC;
@synthesize NavigationBarVC;

@synthesize LibraryButton;
@synthesize OrganizeButton;
@synthesize DiscoverButton;

-(IBAction)next{
    [navigationController pushViewController:LibraryVC animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)next2{
    [navigationController pushViewController:OrganizeVC animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)next3{
    [navigationController pushViewController:DiscoverVC animated:YES];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same syntax like [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:controllername animated:YES];

Comment: I just need to know the connections